# Overriding CreateAPIView, accessing request user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how can I save `created_by` as request user? Note that this field is not defined in the serializer

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('User')

class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'name']

class CreateUserApiView(CreateAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = CreateRequesterSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # how can I save `created_by` as request user?
        return super(CreateUserApiView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the **`perform_create()`** method of **CreateAPIView**

```
class CreateUserApiView(CreateAPIView):
    # your code

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: How does this word if `created_by` is a required field? If the field is not in the post request, validation will fail before reaching `perform_create()`.